# Does the function of a bounded sequence have a convergent subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let {$x_n$} be a sequence in (s,t), and suppose f is continuous on [s,t]. Then does {f$(x_n)$} have a convergent subsequence?

I know if {$x_n$} converges to some $x_0$ then {f$(x_n)$} converges to {f$(x_0)$}, but I'm not sure if {$x_n$} is converging in this question, or how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets.

Comment: How does this apply though? Because {x} isn't compact

Comment: Your interval $[s,t]$, where $s,t \in \mathbb{R}$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is continuous on the compact set $[s,t]$, $f$ is bounded there. That implies, that $(f(x_n))_n$ is a bounded sequence, which has a convergent subsequence by Bolzano-Weierstrass.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks